# Transducers in Haskell and the monomorphism restriction

Tags: haskell, higher-rank-types, transducer, monomorphism-restriction

I implemented transducers in Haskell as follows:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Prelude hiding (foldr)
import Data.Foldable

type Reducer b a = a -> b -> b
type Transducer a b = forall t. Reducer t b -> Reducer t a

class Foldable c => Collection c where
    insert :: a -> c a -> c a
    empty  :: c a

reduce :: Collection c => Transducer a b -> c a -> c b
reduce f = foldr (f insert) empty

mapping :: (a -> b) -> Transducer a b
mapping f g x = g (f x)
```

Now I want to define a generic `map` function. Hence I load the above code into GHCi:

```hs
Prelude> :load Transducer
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Transducer.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> let map = reduce . mapping

<interactive>:3:20:
    Couldn't match type ‘Reducer t0 b1 -> Reducer t0 a1’
                  with ‘forall t. Reducer t b -> Reducer t a’
    Expected type: (a1 -> b1) -> Transducer a b
      Actual type: (a1 -> b1) -> Reducer t0 b1 -> Reducer t0 a1
    Relevant bindings include
      map :: (a1 -> b1) -> c a -> c b (bound at <interactive>:3:5)
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘mapping’
    In the expression: reduce . mapping
*Main> let map f = reduce (mapping f)
*Main> :t map
map :: Collection c => (a -> b) -> c a -> c b
```

So I can't define `map = reduce . mapping`. However, I can define `map f = reduce (mapping f)`.

I believe that this problem is caused by the monomorphism restriction. I would really like to write `map = reduce . mapping` instead of `map f = reduce (mapping f)`. Hence, I have two questions:

1. What's causing this problem? Is it indeed the monomorphism restriction?
2. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: This is because of type inference with higher ranks. The monomorphism restriction does not matter here. No easy fix, I guess, except adding a type annotation or moving to a pointful definition.

Comment: Type annotations don't help: `let map :: Collection c => (a -> b) -> c a -> c b; map f = reduce (mapping f)` still produces the same error.

Comment: The type error tells you exactly what the problem is. The type of `mapping` is silently changed to move the `forall` to the left-hand side (try `:t mapping`). This is a valid (semantics-preserving) transformation, but the typechecker expects the type `Transducer a b` proper, not `Reducer t a -> Reducer t b` (which *could* be distinct types). But when you write `reduce (mapping f)`, the typechecker sees the application of `mapping f` must have type `forall t. Reducer t b -> Reducer t a`, which is the correct type for an argument to `reduce`.

Comment: `let map = ((.) :: (Transducer a b -> c a -> c b) -> ((a -> b) -> Transducer a b) -> (a -> b) -> (c a -> c b)) reduce mapping` works but... yuck. It's the `(.)` that needs the annotation.

Comment: Try `data-fix`, which gives you more general case than transducers, called `F-algebras`. Transducers essentially are F-algebras, but only for list-shaped structures.

Comment: @chi, couldn't that be done as well by annotating the type of each operand? Still not fun, but not nearly as ugly.

Comment: @dfeuer No, annotating the operands does not suffice. The problem is that if you write `f (x :: forall a. ...)` and `f` has a polymorphic type `b -> ...`, then `b` is not instantiated to `forall a. ...` since type variables can be instantiated during inference to monotypes, only. What happens is that `a` gets instantiated to some fresh skolem constant `a0` and then `f` does no longer receive a fully polymorphic value. (Or at least, this is what I understood -- I'm definitely not an expert about how exactly GHC does inference)

Comment: @dfeuer A much simpler explanation: if `reduce` is declared as having type `T`, using `reduce :: T` instead of just `reduce` does not tell GHC anything it does not already know. Type signatures matter when they tell GHC how to specialize a more general type: here `reduce` and `mapping` are used with their full generality, so no specialization is needed. Instead, `(.)` is specialized.

Comment: I encountered the question with similar problem, and hopefully managed to explain why `type` doesn't work better there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27944035/1308058

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make `Transducer` a `newtype`, than the GHC will work out the types much better. Existential type variable won't escape the scope — transducer will stay polymorphic.

In other words, with below definition `map = reduce . mapping` works

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Prelude hiding (foldr, map, (.), id)
import Control.Category
import Data.Foldable

type Reducer b a = a -> b -> b
newtype Transducer a b = MkTrans { unTrans :: forall t. Reducer t b -> Reducer t a }

class Foldable c => Collection c where
    insert :: a -> c a -> c a
    empty  :: c a

instance Collection [] where
  insert = (:)
  empty = []

reduce :: Collection c => Transducer a b -> c a -> c b
reduce f = foldr (unTrans f insert) empty

mapping :: (a -> b) -> Transducer a b
mapping f = MkTrans $ \g x -> g (f x)

filtering :: (a -> Bool) -> Transducer a a
filtering f = MkTrans $ \g x y -> if f x then g x y else y

map :: Collection c => (a -> b) -> c a -> c b
map = reduce . mapping

filter :: Collection c => (a -> Bool) -> c a -> c a
filter = reduce . filtering

instance Category Transducer where
  id = MkTrans id
  MkTrans f . MkTrans g = MkTrans $ \x -> g (f x)

dub :: Num a => a -> a
dub x = x + x

test1 :: [Int]
test1 = reduce (filtering even . mapping dub) [1..10]
-- [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]

test2 :: [Int]
test2 = reduce (mapping dub . filtering even) [1..10]
-- [4,8,12,16,20]
```

---

```
*Main> :t reduce . mapping
reduce . mapping :: Collection c => (a -> b) -> c a -> c b
```

---

Also you could want to check http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2cv6l4/clojures_transducers_are_perverse_lenses/
where definition is `type Transducer a b =:: (a -> Constant (Endo x) a) -> (b -> Constant (Endo x) b)` and various other. Also other interesting discussion.

Comment: Seems reasonable here to make it a `newtype`. Mind though, a lot of great stuff you can with `lens`es depends on the open-lying `forall` in the simple `type`, and wouldn't quite work with newtypes. Not sure how much that might be the case also for transducers.

Comment: Composing transducers can be done by making them a `Category`.

Comment: Edited answer a bit, add link to reddit answer

Comment: is it possible to implement `taking` transducer in similar manner to `mapping` or `filtering`? Tried to do so - but failed :( For me the most difficult part is to reuse `taking` in order to decrement `n`.

Comment: @d12frosted `taking` should be a stateful transducer. To fit in this types above, it should be possible to write `take n = foldr (taking n insert) empty`, for some `taking`. You soon realise it's not possible. `take` is structurally inductive in `n`, not the list (like `map` or `filter`). By making `newtype AutoReducer a b = a -> b -> (b, AutoReducer a b)` it could be possible, but I didn't tried.

Comment: I see. Thank you for you response. I should try playing with `AutoReducer` then.